# controlling the translation of language in a multilanguage web site at one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to do a multilanguage web site. I did the basic parts like translating it to the language I want by using php array. But I want translating every page to that language after changing it at the first page. I don't want to use any plug in. I needed to code it in php so how can i do it? I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION` and storage in there the language, so then you only have to search the arrays in that language.

Example:

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
$langs = array(
    "en" => "Hello",
    "es" => "Hola"
);
```